# NetLogo: communicating between agent-based and system dynamics models

Tags: netlogo, agents

NetLogo can run a SDM and an ABM side by side, but I'd like to go one step further and exchange the value of global variables between the two algorithms. The motivation is to represent some parts of a large complex model using SD, then focus in on individual variations in some other parts of the model using ABM. I realize that this introduces issues of time synchronization, but if I can share variables, I can build my own synchronization mechanisms (e.g., using shared variables to maintain time mileposts), and then go on to construct a hybrid model.

Is there a way I can share variables between two models in a single NetLogo file?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Tabonuco Yagrumo Hybrid model in the models library (under Sample Models > Biology > (unverified)). While the model has problems, it does should how to combine SD and ABM.